# CodeIgniter upload files after preview

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

The flow of my multi-part form is basically **Answer form -> Preview form -> Upload to database**

Right now I upload my files in the Preview step since the `POST` data is fresh from the actual form. My problem is to access `$_FILES` once in the Upload to database function because `var_dump($_FILES)` returns `array(0) {}` once inside `upload_to_database()`.

I thought of actually making hidden `input[type=file]` in the Preview step just so that my `upload_to_database()` will receive `$_FILES`, but this is not possible due to security reasons.

How do I solve this?

#### Edit

Sorry my post above was vague.

I actually want to upload once in the `upload_to_database()` function. I think it's bad practice to upload the user's files in the Preview stage unlike in Upload to database where they are sure of their answers.

The upload is currently in the Preview because right now it only works inside it. The `$_FILES` is empty once we go to `upload_to_database()`.

How can I get a full and presistent `$_FILES` from Preview to `upload_to_database()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could upload your files in the first step (when going to the preview form; like you are doing now), move them to a specific `preview` directory and move them to their final destination when you upload to the database.

I suppose you use something like sessions to keep track of the posted data so you could add the `preview` file path the same way.

Then you set up a simple cron job to delete all files older than xx hours in the `preview` directory every xx hours.

**Edit:** An alternative would be to do the preview completely client-side in javascript, like for example the preview of the questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check my edit, I forgot to mention a key detail. I'm really sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to do something like this:

PREVIEW:

```
upload_to_database($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

DB:

```
function upload_to_database($file)
{
  // work with file here
}
```

I mean to supply $_FILES as an argument to your upload_to_database function

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check my edit, I forgot to mention a key detail. I'm really sorry!